# how to embed webview in an activity to display snippets of html?

Tags: android, webview

all. Would someone give me some clue or instructions on how to add a webview into an activity's views hierarchy and let it show sippets of html?

Answer (score 0):

create an xml in your layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <WebView android:id="@+id/wv1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <WebView android:id="@+id/wv2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

in your activity

```
final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "utf-8";
String nBody = "PUT YOUR HTML HERE" ;
WebView wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv2);
wv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
wv1.setInitialScale(65);
WebSettings webSettings1 = wv1.getSettings();
webSettings1.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings1.setDefaultFontSize(12);
wv1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, nBody, mimeType, encoding, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In res folder create an XML file, in res folder declare your WebView there

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/web" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@color/white" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then in your activity:

```
WebView wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
wv1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "HTML String", mimeType, encoding, null);
```